# Increase fft resolution by zero-padding or Tricking Aforge

Tags: c#, fft, aforge

Hi guys I was looking for a way in order to double or quadruplicate my frequency resolution, I found out [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082358/improving-frequency-resolution-of-fft-output-by-limiting-frequency-range) and asked something like this:

"I asumme zero pad an array (one value between two zeros) would double my frequency resolution (and my output bins will be halfway from they are with my actual code), so, **doubling my quantity of zeros, would quadruplicate my frequency resolution?**"

The other way that I think I could increase my frequency resolution is modifing the Aforge code, thing that I didn't know until yesterday when I found this region:

```
    private const int       minLength   = 2;
    private const int       maxLength   = 16384;
    private const int       minBits     = 1;
    private const int       maxBits     = 14;
    private static int[][]  reversedBits = new int[maxBits][];
    private static Complex[,][] complexRotation = new Complex[maxBits, 2][];
```

If I double or quadruplicate the maxLength and maxBits values, won't it gives me an strange result or an error because of the bits operations or whatever it does?

I didn't copy the whole code, because y thought it would be inappropriate, but if you need it, just let me know, though [here is the website](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/downloads.html) where you can download it.

So, what is the most reliable and/or most efficient way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Zero-padding data to use a longer FFT doesn't really increase the frequency resolution (as in ability to separate closely spaced frequency peaks).  It just interpolates additional points from the same resolution spectrum to allow a frequency plot that looks smoother, and perhaps privides some interpolated plot points closer to frequencies of interest.

But zero-padding is no different from high quality interpolation.